# CSS Alignment problem with Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a little alignment problem with my table. This only occurs with Google Chrome. I would like to have my header checkbox aligned with all checkbox of my table. Everything works well on IE & Chrome until I add the css **table-layout:fixed;**. You can see the result below. On Chrome, the header checkbox is no more aligned with all other checkbox in my table.

[image: Page displayed with Internet explorer]
[image: Page displayed with Google Chrome]

Here is my css:

```
table.search-results
{
  border-collapse: collapse;  
  table-layout:fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

table.search-results td.tipsy-empty { width: 5px;  }
table.search-results td.tipsy       { width: 5px;  }
table.search-results td.checkbox    { width:20px;  }
table.search-results td.favoricon   { width:20px;  }
table.search-results td.idaffaire   { width:50px;  }
table.search-results td.information { width:auto; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden; }
table.search-results td.username    { width:50px;  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post some HTML and CSS in a jsFiddle and it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: @cdeszaq: unfortunately, I try to reproduce the problem in jsFiddle but without success. The page is quite complex (for me at least). I'm a beginner, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CSS reset: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

It looks like the browsers have different default CSS settings for those elements. Always use a CSS reset, don't let browsers control you :)

If you're using Webkit rounded corners, it could also be the problem. Notice how the colored labels also are pushed out. IE doesn't support these rounded corners, which is why they appear as they should. Check Safari, I bet that's your issue. Find a non-css method of rounded corners. They can be a bit ugly, but they prevent things like this.

Comment: i try a CSS reset but it didn't help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Figured. I think your issue lies with the rounded corners. If you're still having this issue, remove the rounded corners and see if that fixes your problem. If it does, find a way to add rounded corners without webkit.